# How to prevent c:\programdata\ subdir having integrity level: low mandatory level?

Tags: windows, security, winapi, uac, integrity

I created a pretty simple application + installer, which relies on including Firefox portable with it.

Originally, during installation I was extracting a Firefox portable zip file to `c:\programdata\<company>\<prod>\firefox` and ran into a weird error when trying to launch it.  Took me a while, but I figured out the reason for this was because all the files in that `firefox` subdir had an adjusted security setting.  They all had "Integrity Level" set to "low mandatory level".  The exact same folder contents without that security setting causes Firefox to work fine.

I couldn't find any documentation online about Windows automatically making `c:\programdata\` files use Integrity Level: low mandatory level.  I guessed maybe Windows when doing creates/writes for files directly under `c:\programdata\` adds this automatically?  I did verify my install helper exe that runs with my MSI, which does the unzipping, is running with elevated privilege's (User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM).

I thought I figured out a fix for this.  Instead of unzipping Firefox directly to under `c:\programdata`, I created a folder under my temporary files directory, extract there, then issue a Win32 `MoveFileEx()` call to move that directory to underneath `c:\programdata\`.  This seemed to work, and I thought this was the answer and was done.  Just recently, though, I got a new PC, tried running my installer on this new PC, and I ran into that same error message again when my app tried to launch Firefox.  I checked under `c:\programdata\` and the Firefox exe had that "low mandatory level" security set on it.

Also, I tried uninstalling my app, reinstalling, and now it appears to be working (no "low mandatory level" permission added yet).  For how long, though, time will tell.

Does anyone know what the deal is with this, and what the best solution is?

I wondered about running `cacls.exe` / `icacls.exe` each time my app launches, to reset file security settings to normal.  My app is made to run at user login and stay running, though, so I don't know the risk of Windows maybe changing the security settings again after my app starts.  In theory, if I had to, I guess I could run the `cacls.exe` / `icacls.exe` every time before it attempts to launch Firefox, but that sounds ugly.

Comment: Just wondering if this happened because Firefox updated itself automatically?

Comment: Pretty sure nope.  Good thought though.  Firefox portable does popup an upgrade available notification box, but I always ignored it.  The purpose of using Firefox in this case is to use an old version before NPAPI plugins stopped being supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mandatory Integrity Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/mandatory-integrity-control), *When a user attempts to launch an executable file, the new process is created with **the minimum of the user integrity level and the file integrity level***. You may need to improve unzip.exe or FileName.zip mandatory integrity.
Mandatory Integrity Control (MIC) provides a mechanism for controlling access to securable objects and evaluates access before access checks against an object's *[discretionary access control list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecGloss/d-gly)* (DACL) are evaluated.

Comment: Yang, thanks, that's good relevant info, but I already understood that part.  What is in question is how/why/when Windows is adding that low mandatory level attribute to Firefox.exe.  For unzipping I wrote custom C++ code for that, it runs as SYSTEM/elevated, unzips to a temp folder dir, then when done does a Win32 MoveFileEx() call to move the unzipped folder to under c:\programdata\. Zip files don't include NTFS security config.

Comment: But you said *I ran into that same error message again* on your new PC. You should check related processes mandatory integrity level.

Comment: There is only one process I can think of. In my MSI installer, it launches InstallHelper.exe /install and this directly in C++ (no invoking external unzip.exe) uses zlib to unzip Firefox.  I checked and InstallHelper.exe is running as SYSTEM/elevated.

Comment: Where do the new created folders and files come from? It's necessary to find out the creator.

Comment: Rather than unzipping a default portable Firefox install file structure, I unzip a version on install that was generated from me actually running it prior on my local pc + adjusting a couple config settings, then zipping up that folder.  After that still some new files/folders like for data cache may come.  These I expect are created by Firefox.exe.